# Prove that $I(t)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^tf(x)\,dx $ is defined on $(-1,\,1)$ and has continuous derivative.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty}xf(x)\,dx$ and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx$ are both convergent, prove that
>   $$
> I(t)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^tf(x)\,dx
> $$
>   is defined on $(-1,\,1)$ and has continuous derivative.

If $f(x)$ is nonnegative, then by comparison test, it's easy to prove it. But how to attack the general case?

Answer (score 2):

You may use Dirichlet's test in the following form: if $h(x)$ is such that $\left|\int_{0}^{t}h(x)\,dx\right| \leq C$ for any $t>0$ and $g(x)$ is such that $g(x)$ is decreasing to zero for any $x\geq x_0>0$, then $\int_{0}^{+\infty}h(x)g(x)\,dx$, as an improper Riemann integral, is convergent. Let us assume $t\in[0,1)$ and define
$$ J(t) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^t \log(x) f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\underbrace{x f(x)}_{h(x)}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\log x}{x^{1-t}}}_{g(x)}\,dx $$
and similarly
$$ K(t) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^t \log^2(x) f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\underbrace{x f(x)}_{h(x)}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\log^2 x}{x^{1-t}}}_{g(x)}\,dx. $$
By Dirichlet's test $K(t)$ is defined for any $t\in[0,1)$. By differentiation under the integral sign $K(t)=J'(t)$.
Similarly we get $J(t)=I'(t)$, so $I(t)$ is twice-differentiable (hence $C^1$) over $[0,1)$.
I will let you to deal with the case $t\in(-1,0)$, which is analogous.

Comment: I have a question. Like you said, $I(t)=\int_0^{\infty}xf(x)\frac{1}{x^{1-t}}\,dx$ given that $t\in[0,\,1)$, then $\frac{1}{x^{1-t}}$ is undefined on $x=0$. I have tried Dirichlet's test, but it requires that $h(x),\,g(x)$ are defined on $[0,\,\infty)$.

Comment: The Riemann or Lebesgue integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx$ are unchanged if $f(0)$ is re-defined, so it does not matter that the integrand function is not defined at the origin.

Comment: I think you might not in the same mindset as me. I am still confused. To be clear, suppose $f(x)$ is continuous, now prove $I(t)$ is defined on $(-1,\,1)$. For negative $t$, I mean that $\int_0^1 x^tf(x)\,dx$ may be an improper integral. I don't think it's just an affair of redefinition, for example, $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ is divergent whatever value of $\frac{1}{x}$ you assume at point $0$.

Comment: @TaoX: in the same way, no matter that $\log(x)$ is undefined at the origin, $\int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\,dx = -1$.